# which iOS time function should I use so it works seamlessly with android

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, timestamp

My server is build with Java and so is my android app (obviously). For certain actions, I require a timestamp from the app. And I store that timestamp on the server. For server and android I use `System.currentTimeMillis()`. So what iOS or Objective-C function should I use so the time is the same? Should I use `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` or `NSTimeInterval timeInMiliseconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]`. Again, I need the time in milliseconds.

Cheaper and faster is always better, and so I was thinking `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()`. But that does not seem to be the correct one to use. Why is that?

In any case, what is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]`, which always specified in seconds. Also, it yields sub-millisecond precision over a range of 10,000 years.

Just multiply the result with 1000 to get the milliseconds.

`currentTimeMillis()` is equivalent to `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000`

Please note that the return value is negative if the date object is earlier than January 1, 1970 at 12:00 a.m. GMT.

`CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` returns the time is measured in seconds relative to the absolute reference date of Jan 1 2001 00:00:00 GMT.

For example, the absolute time -32940326 is equivalent to December 16th, 1999 at 17:54:34.